# How to install ghc on Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, compiling, haskell

I'm now struggling to install GHC on my favourite toy Aquaris E5 Ubuntu Edition. Does someone know how to compile GHC on this machine or cross-compile on OS X?

I do have some experience and knowledge on writing a program package with Haskell and UNIX-like system, but have never ported GHC into a new platform. I've succeeded to install prerequisites such as GCC by using apt-get. However, it's not quite possible to install GHC and Haskell-platform by apt-get due to the limited disk space (only up to 2GB for / directory).

So, I have chosen plan B, that is, to build GHC by myself from the source and install in /home/phablet. I know there're some articles about cross-compiling or porting GHC but it looks like most of these articles are for somewhat older version of GHC. I'm a beginner on this field and so please help me!

Best,
Masa

Answer (score 0):

Get the packages with `apt-get download` and extract files that you need.

Or set up an armhf chroot on Ubuntu/Debian desktop (using `schroot`) and build ghc there. Then take files that you need.